# Kaplan Meier Estimator vs Weibull distribution for water pipe failures

Tags: time-series, survival-analysis

I have a dataset of about 2.6k, featuring all the failures of the water pipe over 20 years. I have also added the right censored data, totaling the dataset (including failures) to be approximately 390k.

From this data, I plotted a KM Estimator to find the probability of failure of the water pipes with respect to time. I then fitted the graph into a Weibull distribution, to check if my dataset is similar to a typical engineering failure. This fitting to the Weibull distribution is to validate if my KM Estimator is correct. My log-likelihood is about -13k.

I want to check if my methodology is correct. On top of that, I want to check what is the acceptable range of log-likelihood. If not, what methodology should I use?